# Making a webpage open only after the user answers a captcha

Tags: php, html

I have a few questions about accomplishing the feature I mentioned.

(1) So I made a page called `sentinel.php` in which I tested out a captcha PHP script that I got from GitHub. Now I'm ready for `sentinel.php` to be the page that opens when someone goes to `MySite.com`. So I changed `index.html` to `home.html` and changed `sentinel.php` to `index.php` and had that page provide a link to `home.html` only after user answers the question. However, when I test out the live link to `MySite.com`, it still goes to `index.html` (which doesn't exist anymore in my control panel). I figure that my web hosting service automatically saves a copy of `index.html` if it's ever deleted without a replacement? Is that what happened? Any thoughts?

(2) Obviously, what I'm trying to do is missing one crucial thing: the fact that the user can simply type in `MySite.com/home` and bypass the captcha. I'm wondering what the proper fix is for the problem.

I hope those questions are clear. I'm new to using sever-side tools. I'll be sure to upvote good answers and pick a best answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

For the second issue. Once the user answers the captcha correctly, set a session variable.

**index.php**

```
  session_start(); 
  $_SESSION['captcha'] = 0;
  //Once you check that captcha is answered correctly
  $_SESSION['captcha'] = 1;
```

Now change your home.html to home.php

**home.php**

```
session_start(); 
if( isset($_SESSION['captcha']) && $_SESSION['captcha'] == 1 ){
      //The user answered the captcha correctly
      //Do your thing
}
else{
     //Did not answer the captcha correctly
}
```